# Session Expire in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing a problem,
I have set session time out in web.config

```
<system.web>
<sessionState timeout="60" mode="InProc" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
```

In my controller

```
public ActionResult CreateBrand()
{
Session.Timeout=60;
Purchase purchase = Session["purchaseItem"] as Purchase;
if (purchase!=null && purchase.Brand != null)
{
return View(purchase.Brand);
}
return View();
}
```

Comment: *I am facing a problem* Find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually ask a question, so I'll take a stab at guessing what you're asking...

```
<sessionState timeout="60" mode="InProc" />
```

When `mode="InProc"`, setting `timeout="60"` usually does not extend the session timeout beyond 20 minutes because the application pool will spin down (by default) after 20 minutes.

No application pool = no process = no session.

Either change your application pool settings or use a different session state provider.